# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fullfilename' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm facing an error as:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fullfilename' referenced before assignment
```

Code block:

```
caminho_path = self.tempDir
arquivos = os.listdir(self.tempDir)

for arquivo in arquivos:
    if arquivo.endswith(".zip"):
        fullfilename = os.path.join(caminho_path, arquivo)

self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

sleep(10)

with ZipFile(fullfilename, 'r') as zipObj:
    listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
    for fileName in listOfFileNames:
        if fileName.endswith('.csv'):
            zipObj.extract(fileName, self.tempDir)
            print('unzip' + str(fileName))
```

Error:

```
File "path...", line 166, in ...

    with ZipFile(fullfilename, 'r') as zipObj:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fullfilename' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: you only set the variable if the if statement is true, yet you try to use it later regardless of the if statement. So if the is statement was false then the variable is not set so when you try to use it later you get the error

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fullfilename' referenced before assignment
```

...implies that you have referenced the variable **`fullfilename`** even before it was assigned any value.

---

In your code block:

```
for arquivo in arquivos:
    if arquivo.endswith(".zip"):
        fullfilename = os.path.join(caminho_path, arquivo)
```

the variable `fullfilename` is assigned a value only when the condition `arquivo.endswith(".zip")` is **`true`**. Else the variable `fullfilename` remains **unassigned**.

In one of such cases when the variable was left **unassigned**, you have tried to reference it at a later part in your code as:

```
with ZipFile(fullfilename, 'r') as zipObj:
```

Even when the variable **`fullfilename`** was still **unassigned**. Hence you see the error.